# In ReactPHP, can I obtain the port number on the local side of the connection?

Tags: php, guzzle, reactphp, tcp-port

I'm running ReactPHP in a Docker environment to listen for WebSocket messages. I use the port mapping feature like so:

```
docker run \
    --detach \
    -p 10002:8081 \
    missive-controller
```

Thus, the external port 10002 maps to 8081 inside the container.

Inside my implementation of `MessageComponentInterface`, I have this event handler:

```
public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg)
{
    echo sprintf(
        "Connection %d sent message \"%s\" to WS server\n",
        $from->resourceId,
        $msg
    );

    /* @var $request \Guzzle\Http\Message\EntityEnclosingRequest */
    $request = $from->WebSocket->request;

    // ... do stuff
}
```

Now, I am listening to a couple of ports in ReactPHP, in order to differentiate between internet WebSocket requests, and private messages from other containers on the private Docker network. So, to detect the port, I do this (using the Guzzle object set up above):

```
$request->getPort();
```

However, that gets me 10002 (the internet port) rather than the internal container-side port (8081). I have a mapping device to look up the association for now, but can I obtain the container port directly?

I am running Ratchet 0.36.

Comment: Silly to ask but did you try a var_dump on the request object to see if the port is to seen somewhere? Technically it is getting the right port so need to evaluate options

Comment: Also post the code where you set both the listeners for two ports

Comment: @TarunLalwani: good idea about dumping variables, I will try that - thanks. I am not sure how the code for listening to multiple ports will help in this regard, but if the var dump does not yield anything, I will add that to the post.

Answer (score 0):

My present answer to this is that it is not possible, at least with the version of Ratchet I am using. I have scanned `$from`, and this only seems to know about the port from an external perspective. The only references I can find in a `print_r($from)` to the internal port are ones that I have set in a manual mapping array, which does not help.

I idly pondered whether this information might be sitting in the `Ratchet\Server\IoServer` server instance, so I injected this into my listener before starting the loop, and examined it with `print_r()` again. Same result, I'm afraid; nothing pops out as looking useful.

Contrary to the original post, my port mappings are now set up in a `docker-compose.yml` file, so my solution for now will be to add these mappings in environment vars in the same file, so it is harder for them to come out of sync. I don't wish to hardwire these, as I am using different port mappings depending on environment.

It is possible that [version 0.4](https://github.com/ratchetphp/Ratchet/releases/tag/v0.4) will support this, so I will revisit when I upgrade.